# My sql trigger, syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, syntax-error

I want to update two columns after current row update by trigger.
endtime and starttime are datetime type. duration is integer and it will represent num of seconds. Sequel Pro tell me "[ERROR in query 1] You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5
Execution stopped!"

```
CREATE TRIGGER `end_time_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `mytable` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE mytable
set endtime = now(), duration = TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, starttime, endtime)
where id = new.id;
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the delimiter. Otherwise the DB will terminate the definition of the trigger at the first `;`

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER `end_time_update` BEFORE UPDATE ON `mytable` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   if NEW.some_col <> OLD.some_col
   then
      set NEW.endtime = now();
      set NEW.duration = TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NEW.starttime, NEW.endtime);
   end if;
END
|
delimiter ;
```

You can't put an update on the same table in the trigger. That would create an endless loop. But you can use `NEW`to refer to the current record to modify it.

Comment: After creation of trigger any update fails:

Can't update table 'mytable' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Comment: You can't put an update on the same table in the trigger. That would create an endless loop. But you can use `NEW`to refer to the current record to modify it. I updated the answer

Comment: juergen, I've used your update answer but now sequel pro tell me: Updating of NEW row is not allowed in after trigger

Comment: Then use `BEFORE UPDATE ON mytable` instead of `AFTER UPDATE ON mytable`

Comment: Hi, if I want to update only when a specified column is changing, how to?

Answer (score 1):

You should set your delimiter so that the semi-colons inside the trigger won't be interpreted as the end of the trigger:

```
-- Set the delimiter
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `end_time_update` AFTER UPDATE ON `mytable` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE mytable
set endtime = now(), duration = TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, starttime, endtime)
where id = new.id;
END;
$$

-- Reset the delimiter
DELIMITER ;
```